# Calling a Rest API with Bearer token

Tags: c#, rest

I'm trying to consume a REST api with bearer token authentication. I'm getting this error:

> Media type is unsupported

Code:

```
using System;
using RestSharp;
using System.Configuration;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

 string Authtoken = "My OAuth token";
 var client = new RestClient(DataserviceURL);
 var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
 request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Authtoken);

        try
        {
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            var obj = JObject.Parse(response.Content);

            Console.WriteLine("Data_" + response.Content);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { string ex1 = ex.ToString(); }
```

Comment: You can mask Authtoken, as it may contains sensitive data

Comment: There is nothing RestSharp can do that `HttpClient` can't. Just use `HttpClient` for everything HTTP. RestSharp is an unnecessary crutch. Also there is more help/documentation available on how to do things with `HttpClient`.

Comment: judging from that error message, i'm not sure that authentication is to blame - what happens when you use a known wrong token?

Comment: cause of your error is not because of the auth token. it's likely how you're sending the request. Check your RestSharp ver cause the default media type in some versions is application/xml, and maybe the api that you're calling accepts only application/json content. So all in all change the content type of your request

Comment: You're doing a POST request but not actually setting anything in the request body.

Comment: Are you sure this is about authentication? The error says different. Typically "media type is unsupported" indicates that your are using a wrong content-type header (or no content-type at all)

Comment: The error is nothing to do with authentication, looks like something to do with the content type. JSON is expected, not sure how to specify JSON. Also. @Andy any sample code for HttpClent option?

Comment: @NelsonKibet: see my response to learn how to specify JSON as your content type ...

Answer (score 0):

You most likely just need to add a HTTP header like this:

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

to clarify what type of content you're sending in your POST body (that is assuming you *are* sending JSON in your POST body - otherwise adapt as needed).
This has nothing to do with your bearer token authentication ...